# How to inform other Activities with Listeners?

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

I have a separate class where my ParseUser is being managed. After it was successful or failed, I would like to inform other Activities or anything with Listeners?

How can i do that?

(EDIT: I was asked to solve this with "Listeners". Never worked with them.)

Comment: Implement observer pattern

Comment: You can use Java Interfaces, that can be implemented as listeners, to communicate between activities and fragments. Take a look at the guide at http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Comment: Send a broadcast and catch it with a broadcastreceiver http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Comment: Using EventBus could be nice, too https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Is the separate class another activity or just an object instance? Maybe the `startActivityForResult()` could be of use?

Comment: Use broadcasts for this kind of communications